# Connect Outlook 2010 to Exchange server without being domain member

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Is it possible to connect to Exchange server without being member of domain network? If yes then how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are given web mail privileges by the network administrator, you must be a member of the domain, and logged in, to access the exchange server resources.

Each network has different settings and security when it comes to how you connect. Contact the network administrator for specific instructions how to connect.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have an account on the Exchange server, then yes you can use Outlook to connect to Exchange without the PC being on Exchange corporate domain network using Outlook Anywhere.

See:
Use Outlook Anywhere to connect to your Exchange server without VPN
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/use-outlook-anywhere-to-connect-to-your-exchange-server-without-vpn-HP010102444.aspx

Of course this feature would need to be enabled by the organization, however in my experience most Exchange installations support it.